# Building Voice Over IP from zero

Tags: c++, sockets, udp, voip

I've been thinking about building a very simple Voice Over IP program, and I thought about creating it through this :

I will record the microphone and every 2 seconds (or maybe it should be even 1 second?) put it into a string (the voice data), send it through socket to the other side, where the other side will automaticly play the sent'd string.

This is the main idea, though I guess I will change a thing or two..

the main question is - will it be fast enough? I'm not looking for a super fast VOIP like Skype, but something which is nice... like 2 seconds deley (ex. after I speak, 2 seconds later the other person will hear me) or something like that...

Will it be very bad? maybe I should use an open library that implents VOIP?
Because I really would like to make something from my own...

By the way, I'll be using C++, and send the packets using the UDP protocol of course...

So what do you think ?

Comment: A bit unrelated to the main question, but the UDP protocol is a terrible choice if you don't care about latency that much (and even then TCP might be better), it's certainly no 'of course'.

Comment: I do care, but UDP is much faster, isnt it ?

Comment: @Amit: UDP is usually used for VoIP, but primarily because it has much lower latency. You're talking about starting with ~2 second latency, in which case the latency of UDP vs. TCP becomes utterly irrelevant.

Comment: This is just a thought. I could also send data every half a second of course. I'm still thinking about the idea.. I was looking for some thoughts about the main idea...

Comment: Why not send data as soon as you have enough audio bytes to make it worth sending?  A standard Ethernet packet is around 1500 bytes, so if your audio samples are 16-bit you could send them every time you've collected 750 samples.  Modern computers are plenty fast enough to handle that, and that would get rid of most of the latency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think I'd do this. The simple fact is that collecting two seconds (or even one second) of voice data before you transmit loses you quite a lot and gains you nothing.

There are a lot of places you can simplify your protocol compared to normal open protocols. A typical protocol has all sorts of options for multiple transmission rates, presence detection, NAT traversal, multiple codecs, etc. These make a normal voice chat program relatively complex. By eliminating the majority of them and just pre-selecting one set of options, you can simplify your code quite a bit.

Sending packets every few milliseconds, however, is *not* difficult. Sending packets every few seconds instead isn't going to make your code any simpler. If anything, it's likely to make the code more complex, because you'll have to deal with storing quite a bit more data. In a typical case, you're dealing with only a few kilobytes of data at a time, so storage is almost completely a non-issue. If you store a lot of data before transmitting, storing the data will start to become a much more substantial problem (though, in fairness, it still won't be exactly terribly difficult).

Personally, I think I'd still use some standard codecs and such so the code and protocol would be easy (or easier, anyway) to expand out to something more complete if you decide to do that. For example, if I wanted to keep things as simple as possible, I'd probably start by using the G.711 codec. Even that supports two forms of compression (mu-law and A-law), so I'd probably choose one of those (probably A-law) and just use it.

Using that, the actual codec (the compression/expansion code) should be well under 100 lines of code (probably closer to 50 lines, depending somewhat on how you prefer to format your code). If you want, you can download the reference implementation from the ITU in [G.191](http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-G.191/en) (Note: G.191 also includes code for a number of other codecs).

That gives you some degree of compression *almost* for free. About equally important, it means you'll structure your code to have a place to call the coder to encode the data before you send it, and decode data after you receive it. If you ever decide to enhance the code, you end up choosing a different encoder/decoder, not trying to add one where none existed before (in which case, you're a lot more likely to need a complete rewrite).

G.711 is intended to operate on a buffer of samples at a time. The supported buffer sizes are 40, 80, 160 and 320 samples. If you don't care about latency, 320 samples would be the obvious choice. Using that, you read 320 samples from your input (microphone), send it to the compressor, put the result into a UDP packet, and ship it over the wire. Repeat as needed. You probably want to include a sequence number in the UDP packet, so the receiving end can play back packets in order. Again, I'd probably follow a standard. [RTP](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3550.txt) is trivial enough that it probably adds only another few dozen lines of code or so (maybe even less than that).

To simplify as much as possible, the receiving code might initially ignore the entire RTP header, and just receive a packet, decode the payload, play it back, and repeat. Later, when/if you find that packet loss and reordering is a problem, you can add code to look at the sequence number and/or timestamp, and act accordingly.

The big point here is that waiting 2 seconds (or whatever) isn't going to make your code simpler. If anything, working with a fixed (and fairly small) number of samples at a time is likely to make the code simpler. You can pre-allocate a couple of buffers of the size you care about, and just use them, instead of dealing with dynamic allocation as you'd probably do for buffering a couple of seconds of data at a time.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment!
I think I will just send packets every milliseconds as you've said.
I will start building it soon, and tell you how it went. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

If you wait 2 seconds before transmitting audio, it won't feel like a conversation. People get annoyed if the delay goes over 100 ms, maybe 200 ms.

Secondly, VoIP applications usually are meant to talk to others. Until your application achieves world dominance, its probably a good idea to foillow one of the established VoIP protocols (H.323 or SIP), so you can talk to others. Just a thought.

Comment: You have to follow a lot more than *one* of the others to get anywhere. SIP (for example) is Session Initiation Protocol. It's basically a few packets exchanged before a conversation can start in which the two ends agree on what codec to use (and such).

Comment: Thanks, but if I will wait 2 seconds before sending the audio, and then another 2 seconds (theoreticly) for the other side to recieve the audio, it means that 4 seconds after I will talk, the other person will get it, which is somehow acceptable... (I can even send the data every 1 second), but will it actually take about 2 seoncds to deviler the packet to the other side, and then play it? I mean, if I wont create a VOIP using a good stable protocol such as H323, it will be MUCH slower? This isnt ment for world use of course, maybe me and a friend talking a bit, or even, just for practice!